# Is there a problem with this geometry question?

Tags: geometry, angle

The answer to the following question is given as option $E:360°$. I can't seem to get this answer. I get $(360-x)°$ as the answer. Is there something wrong with this question?

In the below figure if line $O$ intersects parallel lines $M$ and $N$, what is the value of $u+2x-a+y$

[image]

A. $0°$
B. $180°$
C. $(x+2y)°$
D. $2y°$
E. $360°$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: $v=x=a$, so $u+2x-a+y=u+x+y=360-v=360-x$. However, $u=y$, so $x+2y=u+x+y$, and the question does have a correct answer in the list, namely, (c).

Answer (score 1):

The answer C is correct. It is equivalent to yours, but happens to be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using [formulae](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year8/ch09_geometry/03_parallel/lines.htm) on Angles associated with Parallel Lines

(vertically opposite angles) $y=u,b=d, v=x,c=a$

(alternate angles)$u=b, x=c$

and $u+x=180^\circ$

$\implies y=u=b=d$ and $v=x=c=a$

As $a=x,y=u=180^\circ-x$

$u+2x-a+y=180^\circ-x+2x-x+180^\circ-x=360^\circ-x$

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an option to assign any value to angle $a$, choose $a$ and so every angle as a right angle. $u + 2 x -a + y = 1 + 2 -1 + 1 = 3$ right angles. Option C is correct answer.